# Exposing traefik v2 dashboard on local k8s cluster does not work properly

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I am currently setting up traefik v2 with helm 3 on a local k8s cluster with docker-desktop and I encountered a problem with exposing the traefik dashboard with an ingress route. I think this could be related to the problem that the EXTERNAL-IP of the traefik service remains pending. Has anyone an idea for resolving the problem?

For further information please check out the question on TraefikLabs: [My Question on TraefikLabs](https://community.traefik.io/t/exposing-traefik-v2-dashboard-on-local-k8s-cluster-does-not-work-properly/12432?u=bigd)

Comment: For external-ip being pending. Wait for your local k8s to be fully up and running first. especially coredns (or any CNI) pods must be health. Check this https://github.com/rancher/k3os/issues/208

Comment: @ Narain you are right, that's the solution, if you don't mind you could post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @ BigD Thanks, added as answer. Pls accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For external-ip being pending. Wait for your local k8s to be fully up and running first. especially coredns (or any CNI) pods must be health. Check this github.com/rancher/k3os/issues/208